# Can't run Spring Boot Application due to "unsupported class file major version 61"

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I am doing a project from Jetbrains Academy to learn Spring boot, but when I imported the basic project structure into Intellij, the application doesn't even run at all. I checked my java version and verified that it is version 17, which should be compatible with the spring boot version.

Here is my build.gradle :

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.1.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs = ["src/resources"]

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'com.h2database:h2'
    implementation group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '6.1.0.Final'
}
```

And below is the full error message that I get:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/Users/sofialuk/IdeaProjects/Account Service/Account Service/task/out/production/classes/account/AccountServiceApplication.class]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [/Users/sofialuk/IdeaProjects/Account Service/Account Service/task/out/production/classes/account/AccountServiceApplication.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:452) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:315) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:276) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:132) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:295) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:249) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:206) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:174) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:319) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:533) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at account.AccountServiceApplication.main(AccountServiceApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [/Users/sofialuk/IdeaProjects/Account Service/Account Service/task/out/production/classes/account/AccountServiceApplication.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:60) ~[spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.(SimpleMetadataReader.java:49) ~[spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:123) ~[spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:429) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:196) ~[spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:177) ~[spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:163) ~[spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:284) ~[spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:57) ~[spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
... 25 common frames omitted

I've tried googling this problem and the recommendation is always to check your java version and verify that it is compatible. But if I'm not wrong Spring Boot 2.3.1.RELEASE is compatible with Java 17. According to the Spring Boot documentation, Spring Boot 2.3.x supports Java 8, 11, and 14, as well as any later Java versions.

Would really appreciate any help on how to solve this :)

Comment: The error message clearly indicates that Spring Boot 2.3.1 doesn't support Java 17. Try 11.

Comment: Error is mentioned here . ->Caused by: .....ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file .  Also its good practice to use hyphen or underscore in project name instead of space

Answer (score 0):

*Any recent Spring Boot 2.x release will work really well with Java 17. You can also make use of Java 17 features (such as records) in your own codebases.*

From [spring.io][1]

*Spring Boot 2.3 adds support for Java 14. Java 8 and 11 are also supported.*

From [Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes][2]

So, not recent enough for Java 17

[1]: [https://spring.io/blog/2022/05/24/preparing-for-spring-boot-3-0/#:~:text=Upgrade%20to%20Java%2017,records](https://spring.io/blog/2022/05/24/preparing-for-spring-boot-3-0/#:%7E:text=Upgrade%20to%20Java%2017,records))%20in%20your%20own%20codebases.
[2]: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes